# mysql specific substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a about 500.000 rows in database and they are look like:

```
":hello:hi:"
":bye:good bye:bye-bye:"
":hi:hi-hi:hi-hi-hi:hallo:"
```

So, i need to update my table and remove everything after third character ':' in value, so my result should be:

```
":hello:hi:"
":bye:good bye:"
":hi:hi-hi:"
```

Is it possible? Thx.

MySQL 4.1.22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the function [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) does this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field`, ':', 3), ':');
```